# Как отсортировать элементы ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим у меня на `ContextMenuStrip` есть массив элементов `ToolStripMenuItem`. Есть активные элементы (`Enabled=true;`) и неактивные. Они расположены так - сначала все активные а потом все неактивные. И вот данные изменились, теперь некоторые неактивные стали активными, а некоторые активные - неактивными. Как теперь отсортировать их в порядке сначала все активные, потом все неактивные?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
ContextMenuStrip strip = ...;

var newItems = strip.Items
    .OfType<ToolStripItem>()
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Enabled)
    .ToArray();
strip.Items = new ToolStripItemCollection(strip, newItems);
```